# Java how I get char[][] width?

Tags: java

For example:

```
char[][] something = new char[][] {'Q', 'P','D'},{'A','B','C'}};
```

I know I get height with `something.length` but how I get width?

Comment: if all rows are same length,, something[0].length

Answer (score 5):

Each row may have a different length:

`something[0].length` is the first row's length.

`something[i].length` is the `i`'th row's length.

Comment: Ah, it was that simple. Thank you for replying!